# Вывод данных из таблицы по ссылке в Yii

Tags: php, yii

что-то не нашел в документации как это правильно делать. после генерации crud через gii получаем список колонок только одной таблицы. в списке присутствуют ссылки на поля другой таблицы. как мне их правильно получить? то есть я хочу чтобы в списке элементов таблицы вместо `type_id` мне высвечивался `type_title` из таблицы `type`. надеюсь, что понятно объяснил. поправьте пожалуйста, если я что-то не так понял в этой структуре, с yii недавно совсем связался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мда... надеюсь я вас правильно понял.

У нас есть две таблицы catalog и types.
catalog: id, type_id
types: id, title

Нам нужно сделать связь между таблицами.
Создаем через GRUD для модуля Catalog и Types. Если связи не были установлены при создании таблиц в MySQl (с остальными я не в курсе), значит устанавливать будем сами, иначе оно с генерировалось бы нам GRUDом.
В модель Catalog добавляем:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'type' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Types', 'type_id'),
    );
}
```

В модель Types добавляем:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'catalog' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Catalog', 'type_id'),
    );
}
```

Теперь у нас есть возможность сделать вот так:

```
Catalog::model()->find()->type->title
```

Получаем title типа первой найденой строки в catalog.

Надеюсь я вас правильно понял. И проблема была со связями таблиц

Comment: да, спасибо огромное. а ты не мог бы сказать, как ты бы вывел это?
там контроллер передает данные объекта dataProvider в вид index.php, а тот в свою очередь выводит это во _view.php. то есть во _view.php доступен только объект, который передал контроллер. как правильно это сделать? не хочу городить костыли

Comment: если _view.php генерировал GRUD, то там должны были такие вот строки:

 <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('type.title')); ?>:</b>
 <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->type->title); ?>
 <br />

Переменная $data содержит в себе модель Catalog (из моего примера)

Comment: yahooo! всё работает. спасибо!

Comment: "Теперь у нас есть возможность сделать вот так:`Catalog::model()->find()->type->title`" Это в модели каталога нужно вводить ?